# Fancybox to show inline content by function

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

how can I assign a fancybox to show inline content by function? For certain reasons I don't want to / can't use:

```
<a class="various" href="#inline">Inline</a>
```

How can I do it with a function?

Simplified example (which does not work):

```
$(document).on('click', '#test a', function()
{
        $.fancybox(
        {
            type: "inline",
            href: "#dialog"
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code (like) :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(document).on('click', '#test a', function () {
        $.fancybox({
            type: "inline",
            href: "#dialog"
        });
    });
}); // ready
```

... works perfectly fine, but it's assumed you have :

1). a (hidden) `div` with an `id="dialog"` attribute like :

```
<div id="dialog" style="display:none">
    <h3>Inline Content</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>more inline content</p>
</div>
```

2). an anchor `<a>` tag as a descendant of an element with an `id="test"` attribute like :

```
<div id="test">
    <a href="javascript:;" >some link here</a>
</div>
```

**Notice** you could also target the `<a>` descendant elements of `#test` with this delegated form :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#test").on('click', 'a', function () {
        $.fancybox({
            type: "inline",
            href: "#dialog"
        });
    });
}); // ready
```

... instead of binding the `click` event to the entire `document`.

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your advice regarding the jquery selector. Now it works - don't know what was wrong yesterday.